# Persistent TCP connections in terms of Mobile networks?

Tags: networking, mobile, tcp, network-programming, websocket

I have a questions regarding WebSocket communications in mobile connections.

I was wondering how the long-lived TCP connections can be handled for a long time in mobility networks when the user migrate among different networks. What happens to already established TCP connections when handover (hand-off) occurs?

Do different technologies (3G, 4G or etc) behave differently in this case?

I will appreciate if you could leave some online sources or articles as well that I can read more in this regard?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

The hand-off is always transparent to the user — all TCP and voice connections are always kept active when transitioning between the towers on a commercial mobile network like LTE, UMTS etc.  You might experience some periods of time where the data stops flowing, but that's about it.

I've had several opportunities to verify this myself through an interesting experiment on a T-Mobile USA's *HSPA+* nationwide network.  Take a 12-hour-plus drive from one major city to another one, without turning your phone off.  Take a look at the area where the external IPv4-address terminates (by using traceroute).  You might as well notice that it's still at the same area where you've started your trip.  Now reboot the phone, and see where the external IPv4 address is routed to now.  You'll notice that now it's likely terminated in a major metro area closer to where you are.  I.e., your connection within the core network of the operator follows you along not just within a given city, metro or state, but also between the states and the timezones.

The reason for this is that the carrier has a *Core Network*, and all external connections are handled by the *Packet Gateway* of the *Core Network*, which keeps track of all the connections.  More on this is documented in [Chapter 7](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch07.html) of the book called [High Performance Browser Networking (HPBN.co)](http://HPBN.co).

Comment: i wish i could give you a gold star and buy you dinner. this information is so hard to come by online!

Answer (score -1):

This is not really a SO but more a programmers question and I don't see what you have researched for yourself, but you certainly can't rely on a connection to stay alive, mobile or not.

In fact mobile operators kill long-living connections by resetting them after a certain amount of time or data. So you should be ready to reconnect upon a socket exception anyway.